# 8086 Assembly / MS-DOS, passing file name from the command line

Tags: dos, x86-16

Say I have PROGRAM.ASM - I have the following in the data segment:

```
.data

Filename db 'file.txt', 0
Fhndl dw ?
Buffer db ?
```

I want 'file.txt' to be dynamic I guess? Once compiled, PROGRAM.exe needs to be able to accept a file name via the command line:

```
c:\> PROGRAM anotherfile.txt
EXECUTION GOES HERE
```

How do I enable this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

DOS stores the command line in a legacy structure called the [Program Segment Prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix) ("PSP"). And I do mean *legacy*. This structure was designed to be backwards-compatible with programs ported from CP/M.

Where's the PSP?

You know how programs built as `.COM` files always start with `ORG 100h`? The reason for that is precisely that - for .COM programs - the PSP is always stored at the beginning of the code segment (at CS:0h). The PSP is 0FFh bytes long, and the actual program code starts right after that (that is, at CS:100h).

The address is also conveniently available at DS:00h and ES:00h, since the key characteristic of the .COM format is that all the segment registers start with the same value (and a COM program typically never changes them).

To read the command line from a `.COM` program, you can pick its length at CS:80h (or DS:80h, etc. as long as you haven't changed those registers). The Command Line starts at CS:81h and takes the rest of PSP, ending with a Carriage Return (0Dh) as a terminator, so the command line is never more than 126 bytes long.

(and that is why the command line has been 126 bytes in DOS forever, despite the fact we all wished for years it could be made longer. Since WinNT uses provides a different mechanism to access the command line, the WinNT/XP/etc. command line doesn't suffer from this size limitation).

For an `.EXE` program, you can't rely on CS:00h because the startup code segment can be just about anywhere in memory. However, when the program starts, DOS always stores the PSP at the base of the default data segment. So, at startup, DS:00h and ES:00h will always point to the PSP, for both .EXE and .COM programs.

If you didn't keep track of PSP address at the beginning of the program, and you change both DS and ES, you can always ask DOS to provide the segment value at any time, via INT 21h, function 62h. The segment portion of the PSP address will be returned in BX (the offset being of course 0h).